# change topMost at runtime

Tags: c#, topmost

I am using this code.. now by default my app is topMost = true

But when I try to make a button execute this function below I get an issue, it will disable it once. Then on second click not again.

```
public void setTop()
{
    if (this.TopMost == false)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    if (this.TopMost == true)
    {
        this.TopMost = false;
    }
```

Any ideas why? this has also happen in the past with settings hotkey's from a menu, I was able to do it once then after that it no work :(

Edit: I found out how to do it, but unable to do it from another form with this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pwn4g3 mainForm = new pwn4g3();
    mainForm.TopMost = true();
    mainForm.Update();
}
```

Comment: Code tip: *Never* write `if(x == true)`, and you should probably write `if(!x)` instead of `if(x == false)` too. In this case, though, `this.TopMost = !this.TopMost;` will suffice for the entire method.

Comment: You could also just write TopMost = !TopMost.

Comment: Erm, wait, how do you click it the second time if it got disabled?  Changing TopMost has a lot of possible side-effects, the native Windows window gets recreated.  You'll need to improve your evidence to help us help you.  A small repro project with this problem is best, post it to a file sharing service if it is still too big to post.

Comment: @minitech I did and it failed, I rewrote it to that thinking it may work. But no.

Comment: @hansPassant Like I said I call that setTop(); in the button so if disabled then enable and if enabled disable. But it will not work more then once.

Comment: It now seems like the issue is that I cannot change topMost from another form.

Comment: @minitech,  can you please explain or cite why you state that?  I'm sure you're correct, but I don't know why there's a difference myself and explanation would be educational and appropriate when using a strong assertion.

Comment: @kal_torak it's just a way of cleaner more efficient code. Don't worry don't go back re-coding your app its no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setTop()
{
    if (!this.TopMost)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    else // change this to else. 
    {
        this.TopMost = false;
    }
}
```

In your version when true is assigned to this.topmost, the second `if` condition satisfies. That is the cause of the problem.

**Lets say the code execution starts with false, then first if condition is satisfied, changes to true, checks the second if condition, it is also satisfied, changes again to false.**

Comment: Or you could just do this.TopMost = !this.TopMost  -> If it was false it will be true.  If it was true it will become false

Comment: This would work, correct.. but now the issue is changing it from another form.

Comment: @thorkia That is a great suggestion. I liked it. But I am not sure about readability.

Answer (score 0):

You are not [Showing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) your `Form` in your second example try:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pwn4g3 mainForm = new pwn4g3();
    mainForm.Show();
    mainForm.TopMost = true;
    mainForm.Update();
}
```

Also if you use `mainForm.Show(this);` the second Form will be owned by your `Parent Form` and will be on top automatically.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pwn4g3 mainForm = new pwn4g3();
    mainForm.Show(this);
}
```

But personally if I was wanting to toggle the Topmost property I would have my Form variable as a Class level variable and do something like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    pwn4g3 mainForm = new pwn4g3();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(mainForm.IsDisposed )   //Check that Form hasn't been destroyed
           mainForm = new pwn4g3();
        if(!mainForm.Visible)  //Make sure it is visible
            mainForm.Show();

        mainForm.TopMost = !mainForm.TopMost;
        this.BringToFront(); //To verify zorder of created form
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. that would work, yes.. but issue is that I use a splash screen so it would re-show the splash over and over again on save.

Comment: @Jogn  What are you trying to do? What is this form's purpose.